# Do we need propTypes with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-proptypes

My new react-native project which is setup now uses typescript. So, is it required to use propTypes for type validations since TS already solves this problem? For me, I think use of propTypes will not add any value with since TS handles the type casting issues. Is it correct or should I use propTypes? If so, what are the advantages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`propTypes` is just Reacts form of [typechecking](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), if you are already using a static type-checking library like TypeScript then no, you won't need to use `propType` validation.

React make it clear in their documentation that `propTypes` are an option to those who aren't already using a form of type-checking:

> As your app grows, you can catch a lot of bugs with typechecking. For some applications, you can use JavaScript extensions like Flow or TypeScript to typecheck your whole application. But even if you don’t use those, React has some built-in typechecking abilities.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary nor required to write PropTypes in typed React code.

The only advantage I can think of would be if somebody used the code without type checking he would get the props from PropTypes.